# Selected row background not displayed when using custom gradient on a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, ios5, uitableview

I have the following code that creates a gradient background for a UITableViewCell. The gradient came out great. However when I try selecting a row, I don't see the regular blue highlighted row. If I remove the custom gradient code, the selected row highlights work fine. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TimeTableViewCellList";

TimeTableViewCell *cell = (TimeTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimeCell" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
    //To create the cell gradient

    UIColor *startColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIColor *endColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:247.0/255.0 green:243.0/255.0 blue:238.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[startColor CGColor], (id)[endColor CGColor], nil];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}

TimeEntry * entry = [[self getTimeEntriesBySection:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//..OTHER CELL VALUES SET HERE   

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your gradient layer will be obscuring the selected effect.

Try adding the gradient layer to `cell.contentView.layer` instead. If that doesn't work, you may have to make the layer a property of your cell subclass and change its visibility in your override of `setSelected:animated:`

Comment: Adding to cell.contentView did not help. However overriding the setSelected:animiated: method, as you suggested, works.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution based on @jtruton
The following is the snippet from the cell subclass

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
   if (selected) {
       self.theGradient.hidden = YES;
   } else {
       self.theGradient.hidden = NO;

   } 
}
```